# How to get trasform between multiple frames when some are static and some are dynamic in ros?

Tags: transformation, ros

I have following frames in ros: world ->(dynamic_transform) arm -> (static_transform) camera. Now I would like to get the transform between world and camera, but since static transform is only published once at the beginning of the bag, the timestamps are wrong and I get:

> Lookup would require extrapolation at time 1548686843.013172626, but only time 1548686697.468454123 is in the buffer, when looking up transform from frame [camera] to frame [world]

Now what I thought of doing, but which feels very hacky is to look up the static transforms manually and add them by hand with with the static_transform_publisher. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You should set [use_sim_time](http://www.ros.org/wiki/Clock) parameter and playback the bag file with the [clock option](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Commandline#play) enabled.

Comment: Actually as stated in the question I'm looking for a better less hacky solution.